# How to unwrap list with access variables?

Tags: r, list

I have a list with access variables

```
letters <- list(A = "a", B = "B")

# $A
# [1] "a"
#
# $B
# [1] "B"
```

and I would like to transform this into

```
letters <- list("a", "B")
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "B"
```

How can i achieve this ? I've tried

```
unlist(letters)
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: `names(letters)<-NULL`

Comment: P.D. Do not use the name `letters` since there is a builtin variable with that name.

Comment: `unname(letters)`